# .NET Core 3 and System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle and XamlReader.Parse

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, .net-core-3.0

In `XamlReader.Parse` an XML string, to convert it to a `FlowDocument` I am getting the following error:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''The invocation of the
>   constructor on type 'System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle' that matches the
>   specified binding constraints threw an exception.'

on

```
<Rectangle Stroke="#FF000000" StrokeThickness="3" Width="Auto" Height="3" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
```

Here is the code:

```
public FlowDocument ConvertToFlowDocument(string data)
{
    var x = XamlReader.Parse(data);
    return (FlowDocument)x;
}
```

I should note that error is on `var x = XamlReader.Parse(data)` not the cast.

In Core 3 should something other than `Rectangle` be used?  Should I use something other than `XamlReader.Parse`?

edit: forgot to add that I am converting this to a FlowDocument

edit2: Added the function that converts the string to a FlowDocument

Comment: Could you add some codes example?

Comment: @Auguste I added in some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, took me some time but figured out what the issue is.  So it turns out the error message is a bit misleading.  The actual issue was due to the fact that process is using the above method is another thread.  Even though the `Rectangle` was not part of the UI it acted like it was.  To get around it I had to Invoke it

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate 
{
   //Code that uses ConvertToFlowDocument() method
}
```

If someone could explain to me why that would be great.